# Java board game real-time server, should I use immutability or not?

Tags: java, immutability, observer-pattern

I have been thinking a long time on how to conciliate those 2 requirements for a board game server that notify players in real-time:

- I want to send events to the players (an action in a boardgame can have multiple consequences, I want to animate what happens without re-implementing all the logic on client side).
- I want to expose the state of the game (when a player reloads, I need to send the current state of the game, without replaying all the events).

First requirement tells me "make an mutable observable object".
Second requirement tells me "make an immutable object" to expose state safely.

Which model would you choose to implement the rules? Mutable or Immutable?

Comment: How have you reached the first conclusion?

Comment: I know 2 ways to produce events: either using the observer pattern (which implies mutability), or passing an event bus through every methods that could cause an event dispatch, which feels bad.

Answer (score 1):

Replaying games, connotating single steps, computer algorithms (undo, tries), would favor immutable objects.

That then you want to send the current snapshot to a newly entering user, is a secundary issue: keep a current snapshot, entire picture around.

Comment: Actually, if object is immutable I can expose its data without fear. My issue with immutable objects is how to dispatch events out of them?

Comment: An _event handling_ alters the data model, be adding a new immutable object, and possibly triggering other events. However this might get a bit too theoretical; a model-view-controller separation might be what you are looking for; no events but property change listeners in pure data; and so on. But here I am blabbering already. Start protoyping.

Comment: I already have a prototype mutable. I cannot find a way to implement an immutable version that I can "observe", actually. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Sorry not without concrete code; one may think that a mutable object bridges two immutable states (model), and more is a processing thing (conroller). It is not on/off, yess/no. An Mutable river contains immutable fish (??).